# Validating network geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, geometry, network

I have 2 sets of data:

- A network data and I want to validate it with another
- B network geometry which is a moving van trace data

Since the trace data is very raw without any attribution, is there a way to conclude that I have captured Anetwork wherever BNetwork is present?

I tried simple select by location, but that doesn't work. Plus the data is very heavy (1M + records).

Comment: I am truly suggesting you to focus on a software/tool/library/package otherwise your question can be closed due to vaste options of solutions in (QGIS + ArcGIS)-Domain. Moreover, what have your tried by so far i.e. what is your current research status.

Comment: I'm focusing on ArcGIS mostly. My research is very basic at the available geoprocessing tool level. Trying to get results with whatever options(if any solution) available in ArcGIS at the moment.

Comment: So, in your case I would start tackling the tackle with ArcGIS and if suddenly there will be no solution considering other alternatives make sense. What are your ideas in the scope of ArcGIS? Are familiar with ArcPy as well as with some Python geo-libraries/packages?

Comment: Not tried ArcPy so far but open to any approach or suggestions to keep on track.

Answer (score 1):

I would first Generalize the lines to reduce the vertices to work with and the try Snap or Integrate to capture nearby A Network features. Finally, Select by Location or Spatial Join may be used to get A Network features.